# Play youtube video when clicking on a preview image, php and javascript

Tags: php, jquery

I originally was using this javascript to make a preview image play a youtube video on a click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#feature_content").click(function(){
        var iframe = "<iframe />";

        var url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/SERIAL_NUMBER?autoplay=1&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&hd=1";

        var width = 600;
        var height = 335;
        var frameborder = 0;

         $(iframe, {
            name: 'videoframe',
            id: 'videoframe',
            src: url,
            width: '600',
            height: '335',
            frameborder: 0,
            class: 'youtube-player',
            type: 'text/html',
            allowfullscreen: true
        }).css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '11px', 'left': '11px'}).appendTo(this);

        $(this).find('img').fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();});

     });

    });
```

This code works well, the only problem is now I need to switch the url dynamically...and the variable is with php.

```
<?php 

$url = get_post_meta($id, $youtube[$number], true); // wordpress function 

?>
```

How do I pass the url from php to javascript? Do I just do a jquery ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your PHP output valid Javascript, like

```
var url = "<?php echo get_post_meta($id, $youtube[$number], true); ?>";
```

Comment: this is what I was inclined to do...but I thought you're not supposed to mix up server-side and client-side code?

Comment: But if you're trying to pass a value from PHP to Javascript, I think this is simpler than trying to use AJAX.